# TinyTds::Error: Login faild for user 'sa'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4

I am try to connect `sql-server` through rails console.

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter=> "sqlserver",:encoding=> "utf8",:host => "10.10.10.62",:database => "cosec", :username => "sa", :password => "****")

But i got error..

> TinyTds::Error: Login  faild for user 'sa'

Comment: username is wrong ?

Comment: Go to SQL server error log and there you'll find the reason

Comment: It's not a good practice to use `sa` (or any sysadmin role member) for routine application access.

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this: -

```
development:
  # <<: *default
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  host: 10.10.10.62
  port: 1433
  database: cosec
  username: sa
  password: *****
  timeout: 50000000
```

or

```
   adapter: sqlserver
   encoding: utf8
   database: cosec
   username: sa
   password: *****
   host: 127.0.0.1
   port: 1433
```

Comment: ...and? What is the reason of login failed? His connection string is correct. The problems are with sa login. It can be wrong password, login disabled or Win Auth mode only. **THE REASON IS WRITTEN IN SQL SERVER ERROR LOG**